# Flight mode doesn't enable in the real device

Tags: android

I made an app which can enable the flight mode. It perfectly works for the Emulator, but it doesn't work for the real device(Samsung Galaxy y). Can someone help me on this?

This is the code I used:

```
boolean isEnabled = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0; 
if(isEnabled == false) { 
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED); 
    intent.putExtra("state", 1); 
    context.sendBroadcast(intent); 
}            
} else { 
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
    android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED); 
    intent.putExtra("state", 0); 
    context.sendBroadcast(intent); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reformatting your code, it seems as if the extra `}` before the `else` might be a source of the problem.

Comment: No actualy this is a part of the code. this is working on the emulator but doesn't in the real device. -Anyway-thanks...

Comment: finally i found my own answer use "intent.putExtra("state",true);" instead of "intent.putExtra("state", 1);" and get root for your real device.(Not recomended).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!
I also changed: (0 for false) and (1 for true)
I do not need root device!